# Laravel vue array in array issue

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to get data from 2 database tables and return all in 1 table body in my component.

[image: one]

## code

`controller`

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $history = Payment::where('account_id', $id)->with('account')->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        $balance = Account::where('id' , $id)->select('balance')->first();
        return response()->json([
            $history,$balance
        ]);
    }
```

`component`

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">#</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Note</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(history,index) in histories" @key="index">
                    <td width="50" class="text-center">{{index+1}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center" width="100">
                        {{history.created_at}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center" width="300">Rp. {{ formatPrice(history.balance) }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{history.note}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>

export default {
        data() {
            return {
                histories : []
            }
        },
        beforeMount(){
            let user_id = this.user.id;
            axios.get('/api/account/'+user_id).then(response => this.histories = response.data)
        },
// rest of it
</script>
```

#### In image above

I get my **balance** from `Account` table in histories array while I get **histories** from `Payment` table in histories array.

> What I want is to take out histories array and join it under histories
>   right where there balance data is.
>   So later I can have something like:

```
histories: array[3]
0:...
1:...
2:...
```

How can I do that?

## Update

I've made changes in my controller and now data result become as I wanted (all in one array) but somehow it doesn't return all data.

## code

```
public function show($id)
    {
        // $history = Payment::where('account_id', $id)->with('account')->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        // $balance = Account::where('id' , $id)->select('balance')->first();
        $history = DB::table('payments')
        ->where('account_id', $id)
        ->join('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'payments.account_id')
        ->get();
        return response()->json($history, 200);
    }
```

[image: two]

> It supposed to be 3 but it only returns 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I used push method and now it's working as i wanted. Here is last code for those in need.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $his = Payment::where('account_id', $id)->with('account')->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        $balance = Account::where('id' , $id)->select('balance')->first();
        $history = $his->push($balance);
        return response()->json($history, 200);
    }
```

Hope it helps.